# Shell Script to open VS Code and then the script runs in VS Code Terminal

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, shell, terminal

I have multiple repositories. It's a hassle to manually run them every time. I would like to create a shell script in Linux (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) to automate the process of running my fullstack app. Is it possible to create such a script?

```
# In Linux Terminal
cd backend
code .

# After opening the VS Code, script should open integrated terminal
# And in VS Code terminal, it should run these commands.
source virtual-env/bin/activate
python3 manage.py runserver

# This script runs again in Linux Terminal
cd ..
cd frontend
code .

# This script runs in VS Code Terminal
ng serve --open
```

Optional: How can I make an executable file that, when clicked, runs this script instead of having to copy and paste it into the terminal?

Comment: Did you try ./filename.ps1

Comment: Thanks. I tried /filename.sh and It works. But my main concern is running commands from the Ubuntu terminal to the VS Code terminal.

Comment: VSCode is only for development. To run the code *in production* you use the PowerShell console app.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/vscode/using-vscode?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 1):

This script worked for me. Prerequisites are xdotool.

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

**RunServer.sh**

```
cd backend
code . &
sleep 2
# Maximize the VS Code Window
xdotool key Super_L+Up & 
sleep 2
# Open New VS Code Integrated Terminal
xdotool key Control_L+asciitilde &
sleep 2
xdotool type "python3 manage.py runserver" && xdotool key Return &

cd ..
cd frontend
code . &
sleep 2
xdotool key Super_L+Up &
sleep 2
xdotool key Control_L+asciitilde &
sleep 5
xdotool type "ng serve --open" && xdotool key Return
```

**Optional:**

1. You can modify this script according to your directory and add commands to run the virtual environment.
2. I added an option of 'Run Script' to the context menu of Nautilus (Ubuntu File Manager).
   Refer to this [answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/601291/1705016)

```
/usr/share/applications/run-script.desktop
```

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Run Script
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "%U"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=text/plain;application/x-shellscript;
```

**Drawbacks:**

1. The time required to open VS Code varies from PC to PC and Repository to repository, so some might have to adjust the sleep time.

##### Edit: (More robust script)

```
code /home/user/Desktop/frontend
code /home/user/Desktop/backend

gnome-terminal --maximize -- bash -c "cd /home/user/Desktop/frontend;pwd;ng serve;exec bash"
gnome-terminal --maximize -- bash -c "cd /home/user/Desktop/backend; source .venv/bin/activate;pwd;python3 manage.py runserver;exec bash"
```